# Which PhoneGap project files to store in version control and which to ignore?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm creating 2 PhoneGap 2.3.0 application (1 iOS and 1 Android) using the ./create commands shipped with PhoneGap.

The ./create commands create the whole directory structure with a lot of files and sub directories.

I wonder which files should go into version control (git) and which should not go into version control (.gitignore).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the contents of my .gitignore for an Android app:

```
bin/
gen/ 
.DS_Store
.tmp*
```